# Python datetime найти две ближайшие даты

Tags: python, дата, datetime, время

Нужно найти две ближайшие даты: одна, которая будет будет в будущем, другая, которая была в прошлом.

Сам код:

```
import datetime

date_list = ['2021-12-13 17:30:00', '2021-12-14 12:35:00','2022-01-31 19:00:00', '2023-05-12 12:44:23']
minus_array_str = []
plus_array_str = []
minus_array = []
plus_array = []
now = datetime.datetime.now()
for item in date_list:
    result = now - datetime.datetime.strptime(item,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if str(result)[0] == "-":
        minus_array_str.append(str(result))
    else:
        plus_array_str.append(str(result))
print(minus_array_str, plus_array_str)
```

Вывод из консоли

```
['-28 days, 17:47:51.569381', '-493 days, 0:03:28.569381'] ['21 days, 19:17:51.569381', '21 days, 0:12:51.569381']
```

Какой должен быть вывод

```
Ближайшая дата в прошлом: 2021-12-14 12:35:00
Ближайшая дата в будущем: 2022-01-31 19:00:00
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть осталось... Возьмите максимум из первого списка, минимум из второго, и распечатайте их в нужном виде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

отрефакторил, плюс притащил подсказку @GrAnd

```py
import datetime

date_list = [
  '2021-12-13 17:30:00', 
  '2021-12-14 12:35:00',
  '2022-01-31 19:00:00', 
  '2023-05-1212:44:23'
]

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
past_dates, future_dates = [], []

for date in date_list:
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, date_format)
    if now >= date_obj:
        past_dates.append(date_obj)
    else:
        future_dates.append(date_obj) 

print(f'Ближайшая дата в прошлом: {max(past_dates)}')
print(f'Ближайшая дата в будущем: {min(future_dates)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_list = [
    '2021-12-13 17:30:00',
    '2021-12-14 12:35:00',
    '2022-01-31 19:00:00',
    '2023-05-12 12:44:23'
]
# Эта конструкция будет работать в python 3.8 и выше          V 
dl = sorted([*map(datetime.fromisoformat, date_list)] + [now := datetime.now()])
now_index = dl.index(now)

print(dl[now_index - 1], dl[now_index + 1])
```

```latex
2021-12-14 12:35:00 2022-01-31 19:00:00
```

```py
print(*map(datetime.isoformat, dl[now_index - 1: now_index + 2]), sep='\n')
```

```latex
2021-12-14T12:35:00
2022-01-04T13:42:42.440343
2022-01-31T19:00:00
```